Conversion of Decimal Minutes Seconds into Decimal Degrees when cells within the Columns Contains the Factor 'Missed' in R
Issue
I have a data frame with 388 columns and two of these columns are labelled 'Longitude_E' and 'Latitude_N', containing GPS coordinates in degrees, minutes, and seconds (DMS).
I aim to create two empty columns, and label them as 'Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E' and 'Degrees_Decimal_Latitude_N' because I want to insert GPS coordinates in decimal degrees (DD) into them, which have been converted from the DMS columns.
This data has been collected during fieldwork, and on some survey sheets, the GPS coordinates are missing, so some of the cells contain the factor 'Missed'
For Example:
[1] 33.53.270   33.85.093   33.52.7711  33.52.790   33.52.790   33.51.00    Missed      Missed     
  [9] 33.85.093   Missed      33.50.141   33.85.0925  33.50.20    33.80.14991 33.50.471   Missed     
 [17] 33.49.49.89 33.57.9389  33.57.939   Missed      Missed      33.49.755   33.48.452   33.85.093  
 [25] Missed      33.57.9389  33.48.7932  33.53.27    Missed      33.52.79    33.56.3312  33.55.2628 
 [33] 33.49.2552  33.49.2560  33.48.830   33.56.198   33.49.3460  Missed      33.5279     Missed     
 [41] 33.48.452   33.85.0925  33.51.199   33.51.199   33.52.479   Missed      33.49.2552  33.52.452  
 [49] Missed      33.50.106   33.50.106   Missed      33.85.0925  33.50.20?   33.50.6010  33.50.111  
 [57] 33.40.4042  Missed      33.52.479   33.51.103   33.52.284   38.52.144   33.50.549   33.48.8310 
 [65] 33.52,79    33.52.284   33.52.682   33.85.0925  33.51.493   33.51.007   33.47.078   33.85.0925 
 [73] Missed      Missed      33.850.925  33.53.27    33.850.925  33.850.925  33

I Created two Empty Columns to Insert the DD Values into
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

New_Df<- myDf |>
              mutate(
              Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E = NA,
              Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N = NA,
              .after = 14
              )

New_Df

I can't figure out how to modify the functions (below) so the factor 'Missed' contained within the cells of the columns doesn't interfere with the conversion of DMS to DD, and insert the DD values into the two empty-named columns.
A Section of my Data Frame:
New_Df<-structure(c("33°53'27.0", "33°85'09.3", "33°52'77.1", "33°52'79.0", 
"33°52'79.0", "33°51'00.", "Missed", "Missed", "33°85'09.3", 
"Missed", "33°50'14.1", "33°85'09.2", "33°50'20.", "33°80'14.9", 
"33°50'47.1", "Missed", "33°49'0.0", "33°57'93.8", "33°57'93.9", 
"Missed", "Missed", "33°49'75.5", "33°48'45.2", "33°85'09.3", 
"Missed", "33°57'93.8", "33°48'79.3", "33°53'27.", "Missed", 
"33°52'79.", "27°16'04.0", "27°40'93.2", "27°28'44.", "27°15'85.0", 
"27°15'85.0", "27°21'40.", "Missed", "Missed", "27°40'93.2", 
"Missed", "27°13'20.0", "27°40'93.1", "27°20'45.", "27°31'21.4", 
"27°13'94.9", "Missed", "27°11'44.6", "27°10'85.2", "23°10'85.2", 
"Missed", "Missed", "27°21'68.0", "27°18'19.0", "27°40'93.2", 
"Missed", "27°10'85.2", "27°17'79.2", "27°16'04.", "Missed", 
"27°15'85.", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), dim = c(30L, 4L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Longitude_E_Corrected", 
"Latitude_N_Corrected", "Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E", "Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N"
)))


First replacing "Missing" with NA (using apply since class(mat) is [1] "matrix" "array"), then giving the data to mutate / across. Finally map_vec the strsplit values per variable to get the results.
library(dplyr)

as_tibble(apply(mat, 2, \(x) replace(x, x == "Missed", NA))) %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("^Latitude_N|^Longitude_E"), \(cols) 
    purrr::map_vec(strsplit(cols, "°|'"), ~ 
      as.numeric(.x[1]) + as.numeric(.x[2]) / 60 + as.numeric(.x[3]) / 60 ^ 2), 
    .names="Decimal_Degrees_{col}"))

output
# A tibble: 30 × 4
   Longitude_E_Corrected Latitude_N_Corrected Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E_Corr…¹
   <chr>                 <chr>                                             <dbl>
 1 33°53'27.0            27°16'04.0                                         33.9
 2 33°85'09.3            27°40'93.2                                         34.4
 3 33°52'77.1            27°28'44.                                          33.9
 4 33°52'79.0            27°15'85.0                                         33.9
 5 33°52'79.0            27°15'85.0                                         33.9
 6 33°51'00.             27°21'40.                                          33.8
 7 NA                    NA                                                 NA
 8 NA                    NA                                                 NA
 9 33°85'09.3            27°40'93.2                                         34.4
10 NA                    NA                                                 NA
# ℹ 20 more rows
# ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E_Corrected
# ℹ 1 more variable: Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N_Corrected <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Data
mat <- structure(c("33°53'27.0", "33°85'09.3", "33°52'77.1", "33°52'79.0",
"33°52'79.0", "33°51'00.", "Missed", "Missed", "33°85'09.3",
"Missed", "33°50'14.1", "33°85'09.2", "33°50'20.", "33°80'14.9",
"33°50'47.1", "Missed", "33°49'0.0", "33°57'93.8", "33°57'93.9",
"Missed", "Missed", "33°49'75.5", "33°48'45.2", "33°85'09.3",
"Missed", "33°57'93.8", "33°48'79.3", "33°53'27.", "Missed",
"33°52'79.", "27°16'04.0", "27°40'93.2", "27°28'44.", "27°15'85.0",
"27°15'85.0", "27°21'40.", "Missed", "Missed", "27°40'93.2",
"Missed", "27°13'20.0", "27°40'93.1", "27°20'45.", "27°31'21.4",
"27°13'94.9", "Missed", "27°11'44.6", "27°10'85.2", "23°10'85.2",
"Missed", "Missed", "27°21'68.0", "27°18'19.0", "27°40'93.2",
"Missed", "27°10'85.2", "27°17'79.2", "27°16'04.", "Missed",
"27°15'85."), dim = c(30L, 2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Longitude_E_Corrected",
"Latitude_N_Corrected")))


Hey Andre, thank you for answering my question, I really did appreciate this. I've tried to use your code on my data frame, and on the data frame you posted 'mat' and it isn't working. The DD conversion is not being inserted into the empty columns I created in the data frame I posted. I don't know what is going wrong. Could you please help me fix it? I'm not an expert, so thank you so much. All the best!

There's no need to create NA columns, they're coming from across. That's why they are not there in mat. Did you use the example data and you do not see the new columns?

I just used the example data 'mat' and ran your code and the output was a tibble of the data frame 'mat', but not with the column Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E_Corr…¹ with DD values. I tried separating my longitude and latitude columns from my data frame and I got the same result. Do you know what might be going wrong since this worked for you? Many thanks for your time and efforts, Andre. I really appreciate this

Just to clarify, if you run the code the original matrix mat is not changed. You have to assign it to a variable to be able to access it later, e.g. new_mat <- as_tibble(apply(mat, 2, \(x) replace(x, ...

Thank you! I have been assigning the matrix to a variable and for some reason, the decimal degrees values are not being outputted. Both your and Margusl code works as you've posted your outputs. I have added the function you wrote (method 1) in the form that I'm using and I have posted the output that I'm getting. I don't know what's going wrong. Do you have any ideas? Thank you for your time and patience.

I get the correct output, whatever I am doing, using mat or New_Df. I can't imagine what can go wrong when you: 1. Start a new R session, 2. Load the library library(dplyr), 3. get the data by copying mat <- structure(c("33 ..., 4. Execute as_tibble(apply(mat, 2, \(x ....

Using included example data (matrix) and measurements::conv_unit():
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# cleaning input for measurements::conv_unit()
clean_dms_str <- function(dms_str){
  dms_str |> 
    str_to_lower() |> 
    na_if("missed") |> 
    # measurements::conv_unit() expects one space between subunits (e.g. 70° 33’ 11” = "70 33 11")
    # replace non-digits with " " (except "."), 
    # make sure every second ends with a digit, "33 51 00." >> "33 51 00.0"
    str_replace_all(pattern = c("[^0-9.]" = " ", "\\B$" = "0"))
}
# test
clean_dms_str(c("33°52'79.0", "33°51'00.", "Missed"))
#> [1] "33 52 79.0" "33 51 00.0" NA

# first 2 matrix columns to a frame, apply conversion to "*Corrected" columns
dec_deg_df <- 
  New_Df[,1:2] |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(across(ends_with("Corrected"), 
                list(DD = \(x) 
                     clean_dms_str(x) |> 
                       measurements::conv_unit(from = "deg_min_sec", to = "dec_deg") |> 
                       as.numeric() |> 
                       # just to format tibble print ouput, does not change values
                       tibble::num(digits = 4)
                     ),
                .names = "{str_sub(.col, 1, 3)}_{.fn}")
         ) 

Result:
dec_deg_df
#> # A tibble: 30 × 4
#>    Longitude_E_Corrected Latitude_N_Corrected    Lon_DD    Lat_DD
#>    <chr>                 <chr>                <num:.4!> <num:.4!>
#>  1 33°53'27.0            27°16'04.0             33.8908   27.2678
#>  2 33°85'09.3            27°40'93.2             34.4192   27.6926
#>  3 33°52'77.1            27°28'44.              33.8881   27.4789
#>  4 33°52'79.0            27°15'85.0             33.8886   27.2736
#>  5 33°52'79.0            27°15'85.0             33.8886   27.2736
#>  6 33°51'00.             27°21'40.              33.8500   27.3611
#>  7 Missed                Missed                 NA        NA     
#>  8 Missed                Missed                 NA        NA     
#>  9 33°85'09.3            27°40'93.2             34.4192   27.6926
#> 10 Missed                Missed                 NA        NA     
#> # ℹ 20 more rows


-e-
If you need to update source New_Df matrix with new columns from dec_deg_df tibble, you can for example cbind() relevant subsets. Note the use of as.matrix() and that numerics are converted to characters to match matrix data type.
cbind(New_Df, as.matrix(dec_deg_df[, c("Lon_DD","Lat_DD")])) |> head(10)
#>       Longitude_E_Corrected Latitude_N_Corrected Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N Lon_DD             Lat_DD            
#>  [1,] "33°53'27.0"          "27°16'04.0"         NA                          NA                         "33.8908333333333" "27.2677777777778"
#>  [2,] "33°85'09.3"          "27°40'93.2"         NA                          NA                         "34.41925"         "27.6925555555556"
#>  [3,] "33°52'77.1"          "27°28'44."          NA                          NA                         "33.8880833333333" "27.4788888888889"
#>  [4,] "33°52'79.0"          "27°15'85.0"         NA                          NA                         "33.8886111111111" "27.2736111111111"
#>  [5,] "33°52'79.0"          "27°15'85.0"         NA                          NA                         "33.8886111111111" "27.2736111111111"
#>  [6,] "33°51'00."           "27°21'40."          NA                          NA                         "33.85"            "27.3611111111111"
#>  [7,] "Missed"              "Missed"             NA                          NA                         NA                 NA                
#>  [8,] "Missed"              "Missed"             NA                          NA                         NA                 NA                
#>  [9,] "33°85'09.3"          "27°40'93.2"         NA                          NA                         "34.41925"         "27.6925555555556"
#> [10,] "Missed"              "Missed"             NA                          NA                         NA                 NA

Or update some existing columns in New_Df matrix with values from dec_deg_df tibble:
New_Df[, c("Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E", "Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N")] <- as.matrix(dec_deg_df[, c("Lon_DD","Lat_DD")])
head(New_Df, 10)
#>       Longitude_E_Corrected Latitude_N_Corrected Decimal_Degrees_Longitude_E Decimal_Degrees_Latitude_N
#>  [1,] "33°53'27.0"          "27°16'04.0"         "33.8908333333333"          "27.2677777777778"        
#>  [2,] "33°85'09.3"          "27°40'93.2"         "34.41925"                  "27.6925555555556"        
#>  [3,] "33°52'77.1"          "27°28'44."          "33.8880833333333"          "27.4788888888889"        
#>  [4,] "33°52'79.0"          "27°15'85.0"         "33.8886111111111"          "27.2736111111111"        
#>  [5,] "33°52'79.0"          "27°15'85.0"         "33.8886111111111"          "27.2736111111111"        
#>  [6,] "33°51'00."           "27°21'40."          "33.85"                     "27.3611111111111"        
#>  [7,] "Missed"              "Missed"             NA                          NA                        
#>  [8,] "Missed"              "Missed"             NA                          NA                        
#>  [9,] "33°85'09.3"          "27°40'93.2"         "34.41925"                  "27.6925555555556"        
#> [10,] "Missed"              "Missed"             NA                          NA

Created on 2024-09-15 with reprex v2.1.1

Hello Margusl. Thank you so much for your answer. That's exactly the result I'm looking for. I'm attempting to use this code on my data frame. The column numbers for Lattitude_N and Longitude_E are columns 13 and 14. The columns created for the DD values are column numbers 15 and 16. Would you be able to instruct me on what info I need to add to your code? The name of my data frame is Df, so I replaced New_Df[,1:2] with Df[,13:14].  Did you use the data frame 'mat' or my reproducible data? Thank you for your patience, I'm not an expert here. Good way to learn

Well, it's basically identical result to Andres' solution., both are 30x4 frames. I used your example data as-is, note that it is not a data frame but a matrix. Major difference (in your case) is that you can't have different column types in a matrix, e.g. it's either all character or all numeric. And you can't really modify matrix with dplyr.  I'm afraid I don't quite follow your question, but you really should not care about column numbers or column order at this stage, just names.  You can set exact order through dplyr::select() or dplyr::relocate() as a final step if needed.

@AliceHobbs ,  if by any chance your follow-up question was related to adding decimal degree columns (or column content) to the source matrix, perhaps this last edit helps.

Hey Margusl. This question is about adding the decimal degree columns to the matrix as I'd like four columns for latitude and longitude in both DMS and  DD next to each other as they'll be inputted into GIS software for analysis. I have put your code into the question (see above) and I have posted the form of the code you have written and the output that I'm getting. Both your and Andre's code works as you've both posted your outputs, but for me, the DD values are not being outputted. I don't know what is going wrong. Do you have any ideas? Thank you so much for your patience and time.

Are there any warnings? Packages are up to date? Any changes when you start a new R session and test with a data example from your own question, New_Df<-structure(c("33°53'27.0", ... ?

Finally, Andre and Margusl. I got both codes to work. R Studio wanted a package called 'measurements' to be downloaded, and I shut R Studio down, restarted everything and now both codes work. Thank you, thank you, thank you.
